# Showing that E(E(Y|A))|B) = E(Y|A,B)?

Tags: conditional-expectation

Would $E(   E(Y|A)  |  B) = E(Y|A,B)$? How does one show this? Intuitively, it make sense that conditioning on this one at a time would result in the same thing as conditioning all at once.

Comment: I'm assuming A and B are random variables, correct? I'm also assuming that A and B are not necessarily independent.

Comment: Yes, these are indeed random variables.

Comment: And yes, they are not necessarily independent.